# How can I remove Windows XP from harddrive

Tags: windows-xp

I installed Ubuntu for the first time. I am very happy with it.  My question is How can I erase Windows XP from my Hard drive and just keep Ubuntu?  I Finally had success with the direct download to my hard drive after several failures on DVD and Cd's I would like to totally get rid of XP.!

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the ubuntu app store, and get Disk Utility, select your hard drive, click on the part that has XP, and then you can delete that partition. (This is in 12.04, it might be a different program in 13.10)

BE VERY CAREFUL THOUGH NOT TO DELETE YOU UBUNTU PARTITION!!!!